# Entity Framework Core creating a duplicate foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET Core 6 with Entity Framework Core 6. I have seen many questions on StackOverflow regarding this issue but they are outdated. lots of methods are changed in Entity Framework Core 6.

Here is my model class:

```
    [Key]
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual SUser SUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("KeyId")]
    public Guid KeyId { get; set; }
    public virtual SKey SKey { get; set; }
```

In my DB context I am modeling a database on creating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SFile>()
            .HasOne(x => x.SKey)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

When I see the tables keys in SQL I saw it created `SKeyId` two times with names `SKeySkeyId` and `SkeySkeyId1`.

Comment: *but they are outdated* - curious how questions about a version of EFC that was released 5 months ago, and is current, can be "outdated"

Comment: ```HasRequired()```, ```HasOptional()```, ```WillCascadeOnDelete()``` are not available in current version

Comment: Perhaps, for an easy life, you should name your properties according to conventions EFC understands; SUserId, not UserId. SKeyId, not KeyId. This way EFC will understand SUser and SUserId are paired. There are other ways to configure disparity in naming if you want to keep it but convention is easiest

Comment: I think you must set the foreignKey because you aren't in the EFCore conventions name `.HasForeignKey(x => x.KeyId);`

Comment: The `[ForeignKey]` attributes are on the wrong properties. But you better remove the attributes altogether an do everything, including indicating FK properties, in fluent mapping.